# Create a VIEW for Hive Table by defining schema for a column which has JSON

Tags: hive, hdfs, avro, parquet

1. I'm storing the Raw JSON string from my Kafka stream to HDFS as parquet
2. I have created an external table on Hive for the HDFS folder
3. Now I want to create a VIEW for the RAW data stored in the Hive table,

Kafka Stream to HDFS

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String brokers = "quickstart:9092";
    String topics = "simple_topic_6";
    String master = "local[*]";

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder().appName(EventKafkaToParquet.class.getName())
            .master(master).getOrCreate();
    SQLContext sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext();
    SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
    context.setLogLevel("ERROR");

    Dataset<Row> rawDataSet = sparkSession.readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
            .option("subscribe", topics).load();
    rawDataSet.printSchema();

    rawDataSet = rawDataSet.withColumn("employee", rawDataSet.col("value").cast(DataTypes.StringType));
    rawDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("basicView");
    Dataset<Row> writeDataset = sqlContext.sql("select employee from basicView");
    writeDataset
            .repartition(1)
            .writeStream()
            .option("path","/user/cloudera/employee/")
            .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/cloudera/employee.checkpoint/")
            .format("parquet")
            .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(5000))
            .start()
            .awaitTermination();
}
```

External table on Hive

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE employee_raw ( employee STRING )  
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/employee' ;
```

Now I want to create a HIVE view on top of employee_raw  table, which gives the out put as

```
firstName, lastName, street, city, state, zip
```

The  output of employee_raw table is

```
hive> select * from employee_raw;
OK
{"employee":{"firstName":"Ganesh","lastName":"Kumar","address":{"street":"1400 Dakota Dr","city":"Princeton","state":"NJ","zip":"09800"}}}
{"employee":{"firstName":"Ganesh","lastName":"Kumar","address":{"street":"1400 Dakota Dr","city":"Princeton","state":"NJ","zip":"09800"}}}
{"employee":{"firstName":"Ganesh","lastName":"Kumar","address":{"street":"1400 Dakota Dr","city":"Princeton","state":"NJ","zip":"09800"}}}
{"employee":{"firstName":"Ganesh","lastName":"Kumar","address":{"street":"1400 Dakota Dr","city":"Princeton","state":"NJ","zip":"09800"}}}
{"employee":{"firstName":"Ganesh","lastName":"Kumar","address":{"street":"1400 Dakota Dr","city":"Princeton","state":"NJ","zip":"09800"}}}
Time taken: 0.123 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Your inputs are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your description it looks for me that you mainly like to "[Extract values from JSON string in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514710/)", so you may find the answer in the [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516319/6771046).